# Prime ideals are determined by maximal ideals for a large class of rings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the book Basic Algebraic Geometry 2 by Shafarevich, the author writes

> For a large class of rings, the set of prime ideals is determined by maximal ideals.(P. 5)

In what sense this determination is understood or the author wants to say? What class of rings satisfy this thing, just as a simple example?

Comment: Is there any chance that there’s a particular kind of ring under discussion here?

Comment: I think no, he mostly considrs coordinate rings, I think

Comment: “most of the rings” is not how someone fluent in (American) English would likely describe rings in general. You would say “most rings.” The use of the definite article makes it seem like it’s short for “most of the rings under discussion” or “most of the rings I have introduced” to me. That, together with the fact that I have no idea what the author means, is why I ask.

Comment: Coordinate ring means we can look only at $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Possibly the goal would be to generalize this, using morphisms and the Krull dimension : $(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal of $K[x,y ]$, and $x K[x]
 = ((x,y) \cap K[x]) K[x,y]$ is a prime ideal of $K[x,y]$.

Comment: Biderman: I edited grammatically few things

Comment: For finitely generated algebras over a field any prime ideal is the intersection of all maximal ideals containing it. That is to say, the closed points determine the variety. May be that is what Shafarevich means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (commutative) [Jacobson ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring) is a (commutative) ring in which every prime ideal is an intersection of maximal ideals; thus geometrically we can think of the closed subscheme cut out by any prime ideal as consisting of a collection of "points," namely the subschemes cut out by the corresponding maximal ideals. A general version of the [Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz) guarantees that every finitely generated algebra over a Jacobson ring is another Jacobson ring; in particular, finitely generated algebras over a field are Jacobson rings, which correspond to closed subschemes of affine $n$-space $\mathbb{A}^n$ over a field.

Comment: Very nice, I have no idea of schemes since I just began Algebraic Geometry, but this answer gives some insight into Shafarevich's comment. Thanks.